# C++ array output problem in VS2008 with OpenCV

Tags: c++, arrays, visual-studio-2008, opencv

I'm making a texture classifier in OpenCV and VS2008 and I want to insert 3 double variables into a double array so I can calculate nearest neighbours of the arrays.

I tried :

`double a[5]={x,y,z};`

and the output is 0012FF04

the same output happens when I just declare an array with a couple of numbers in it like 
double: 
   `b[2]={1.0,2.3};`

And finally when I tried to declare the array long double it went into debug and gave me an exception and the console output was: `0012FED4OpenCV Error:Bad flag <parameter or structure field> <Unrecognized or unsupported array type> in unknown function, file .\cxarray.cpp, line 2470.`

If anyone could help me I would be very grateful.

Comment: You're obviously passing bad arguments to a function, but you haven't shown us a single line of the actual code. You'd need to show the real code where you define the array, the code where you're passing this array to a function, and if you showed the declaration of that function, that would help too. The above "code" is mostly uncompilable -- you have to actually cut-and-paste the real stuff.

Comment: Here is the whole class [link](http://codepaste.net/9vovb3) and a printscreen with the output [link](http://i.imgur.com/fJvgR.jpg) , rest of the program handles with the calculation of those glcm values (those doubles I'm trying to insert) so it doesn't have much to do with it. If you could point me out to an article or a tutorial it be great since I'm pretty bad with this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

C++ doesn't define an `operator<<(double*)` that displays the contents of an array; C++ arrays aren't self-describing  and I don't believe defining such an operator in a generally-useful way would be possible. You have to write an explicit loop:

```
for (int i=0; i<3; ++i)
    std::cout << brick_v[i] << " ";
std::cout << std::endl;
```

Comment: Thanks a lot, I forgot about that

Answer (score 0):

Why don't you use a `std::vector<double>` instead of a raw array, and then you can call `push_back` to insert values.

If you need to pass it to a function that takes a raw array or pointer, you can just do `&v[0]` or for an array `v[0]`.

Just a suggestion.